# Locally stored data causing Android application to show blank activity on Samsung

Tags: android, caching, samsung-mobile

I have an application that is suposed to flow as follows:

1. Application starts on a Splash Screen, after a few seconds it takes me to the main activity
2. Once on the main activity, the application detects if the user has logged in, if he has he is taken to step 3, otherwise he is taken to step 4
3. If user has logged in, it shows the user's data activity
4. If the user has not logged in, it shows the log in activity

When updating the application to a new version however, the application gets stuck in the main (blank) activity, but only on Samsung devices. I found that the application continues working correctly once we go to and manually delete the app's stored cache data.

I have tried by adding `android:allowBackup='false'` and `android:fullBackupContent='false'` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file but the problem persists.

Comment: have you added `tools:replace="android:allowBackup` as well?

Comment: @lyncx no, should I place it on the Manifest?